# 1px diffrence with text and textinput in react native

Tags: css, react-native, tailwind-css

I am using nativewind. The problem is text input and text isnt lined the diffrence is 1px you can see in the image i didnt added any paddings they are in the same view. How i can fix this problem?

[Diffrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1U2X.jpg)

```
        <View className=" flex w-10/12 flex-row items-center focus:bg-fixinput dark:bg-fixinputDark">
          <Text className="text-lg text-black pl-1">
            {countryJson.find((country: any) => country.code === 'AT').dial_code}
          </Text>
          <TextInput
            ref={phoneInputRef}
            value={phone}
            maxLength={10}
            onChangeText={setPhone}
            keyboardType="phone-pad"
            placeholder="Your Phone Number"
            autoComplete="tel"
            autoCorrect={false}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            placeholderTextColor={'#999'}
            className=" rounded text-red-500 text-lg h-20"
          />
        </View>
```

I tried giving same height to the text and textinput but didnt solved the issue

Comment: Play around with line-height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue the problem was coming from the parent view i sized as h-12 but it was too small for the font size. While textinput is empty textinputs height is smaller there is no problem it can center it but when i added a value the textinputs height changes so it moves. The fix is using better height parameter for the parent view. It was really easy to fix problem but i didn't manage to find i asked chatgpt first i got the same line height problem it made me to look another places and i lost a lot of time.